# How to iterate the result of combination padlock until condition fulfilled, then break, without creating cartesian product first?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

For example, suppose I have a combination padlock, which can be simulated with 2d array:

```
const array_2d=[
    ["HUGE","TALL","TINY"],
    ["BLUE","CYAN","DARK","GOLD","GRAY"],
    .
    .
    .
    (other wheels)
    ["BIRD","FISH","GOAT","MOTH"]
];
```

which each inner array represents a wheel of the lock. In the business code I would like to iterate the result until some conditions fulfilled, for example, in simple here, move the wheel until a combination has 3 or more "A",ie:

```
TALL ... ... ... CYAN GOAT
```

How to write loops that iterates the result of those combinations of wheels:

```
HUGE BLUE ... ... ... BIRD
HUGE BLUE ... ... ... FISH
.
.
.
HUGE CYAN ... ... ... BIRD
HUGE CYAN ... ... ... FISH
.
.
.
```

until condition fulfilled (3 or more "A"):

```
TALL ... ... ... CYAN GOAT
```

?

I don't want to create cartesian product first and then iterating those cartesian product result, because in business code the incoming data may be very large, and there may have many wheels. I tried (simplify the case to 3 wheels only):

```js
const array_2d=[
  ["HUGE","TALL","TINY"],
  ["BLUE","CYAN","DARK","GOLD","GRAY"],
  ["BIRD","FISH","GOAT","MOTH"]
];
for(let i=0;i<array_2d.length;i++){
  let str="";
  for(let j=0;j<array_2d[i].length;j++){
    str+=array_2d[i][j]+" ";
  }
  if(str.split("A").length-1>=3){
      document.write(str+"<br/>");
      break;
  }
}
```

which the expected result is:

```
TALL GRAY GOAT
```

but the actual result is:

```
BLUE CYAN DARK GOLD GRAY
```

which is not working.

Comment: Well it is working; the result you get satisfies your condition. It just happens to be the first one that does. Are there more criteria than this? Do you need the *shortest* combination?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can use the regular cartesian array [creator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12303989/87713) and filter result by conditions.
But if the number of arrays is increasing, it's better to use the generator function to create next value.

Here are both solutions, a live demo:

```js
const array_2d=[["HUGE","TALL","TINY"], ["BLUE","CYAN","DARK","GOLD","GRAY"],["BIRD","FISH","GOAT","MOTH"]];

const condition = (arr) => [...arr].every((term) => term.includes('A'));

// Solution
const cartesian = (...a) => a.reduce((a, b) => a.flatMap(d => b.map(e => [d, e].flat())));
  
const result = cartesian(...array_2d).filter(condition);

console.log('Regular solution:\n', result);


// Generator solution
function* cartesianGen(head, ...tail) {
  const remainder = tail.length > 0 ? cartesianGen(...tail) : [[]];
  for (let r of remainder) for (let h of head) yield [h, ...r];
};

const codeGen = cartesianGen(...array_2d);

let code = {};
do {
  code = codeGen.next();
  if (condition(code.value)) break;
} while (!code.done);

console.log('Generator solution:\n', code.value);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```